# ics with alert?

Tags: alert, icalendar, rfc2445, rfc5545

Hi I just found out about the ics file format, and I'm wondering whether its possible to include one or 2 alert points in an event entry which will automatically get picked up?

code:

```
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART;TZID=Europe/Amsterdam:20130214T190000
DTEND;TZID=Europe/Amsterdam:20130214T190000
URL:http://www.myurl.com
DTSTAMP:20130205T114500
UID:
CREATED:20130214T190000
DESCRIPTION:Wedstrijd":" 3000H5B2  CE\, Datum":" donderdag 14 februari - 19.00
```

And for an alert something like:

```
DTALERT1;Europe/Amsterdam:20130213T190000
```

or even nicer:

```
DTALERT1;DTSTART-24H
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

for more details refer to [RFC5545 ALARM component](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.6.6), in your case the resulting icalendar file would look like:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:pyICSParser
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART:20130214T190000
DTEND:20130214T190000
URL:http://www.myurl.com
DTSTAMP:20130205T114500
UID:UID
CREATED:20130214T190000
DESCRIPTION:Wedstrijd":" 3000H5B2  CE\, Datum":" donderdag 14 februari - 
 19.00
BEGIN:VALARM
TRIGGER:-PT24H
REPEAT:1
DURATION:PT15M
ACTION:DISPLAY
DESCRIPTION:Reminder
END:VALARM
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Comment: This has worked well for 5 years but now Apple calendar does not recognize the valarm anymore. Instead it is monitoring my location, traffic conditions and telling me when it's time to leave by car, which is inappropriate because most of the time there is alcohol involved and I take my bicycle.

Comment: @drjerry it still works... try this: 
`BEGIN:VALARM
TRIGGER:-PT60M
ACTION:DISPLAY
END:VALARM`

Answer (score 5):

This still works in 2021 November:

```
BEGIN:VALARM
X-WR-ALARMUID:12E16C3A-108C-1639-AABD-AF32053AC32E
UID:10E16C3A-128C-1639-AABD-AF32053AC32E
TRIGGER:-PT5M
DESCRIPTION:Reminder
ACTION:DISPLAY
END:VALARM
```

***You can add this block right before END:VEVENT***

The unique alarm UIDs are required.

Comment: Working and nice solution.

Comment: Do you have a reference for the format? RFC?

Comment: @oligofren: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc9074#section-4